# Keyboard character @ in wrong location

Tags: 12.10, keyboard-layout

After loading 12.10 found keyboard character `@` was not <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> displays `"`.
I did not have this problem with the same keyboard in 12.04 version.
How can I change the `@` to the correct location on my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the system menu (the "power cog" indicator at the top right corner of the screen) > System Settings..., and from there go to Keyboard Layout. There you can add your keyboard layout (using the plus sign button), possibly English (US) according to the location of the @ sign you mention, and remove the one you currently have configured.